# pipe loop to out-gridview and clear grid on every loop?

Tags: powershell, out-gridview

I'm just wondering if I can clear Out-Gridview on every loop like I can in the console:

```
while (1) { ps | select -first 5; sleep 1; clear-host }
```

Unfortunately this doesn't clear out-gridview every time:

```
 & { while (1) { ps | select -first 5; sleep 1; clear-host } } | out-gridview
```

Comment: all the `*-Host` cmdlets go _directly to the console host screen_. that means you are NOT sending any clear command to anything other than the console ... and `Out-GridView` is _not_ a console app - it's a GUI app. if you want to clear it ... close it and then reopen it.

Answer (score 2):

`Clear-Host` clears the display of the *host*, which is the *console window*'s content in a regular PowerShell console.

By contrast, `Out-GridView` is a *separate GUI window*, over which PowerShell offers no programmatic display once it is being displayed.
Notably, you can neither clear no refresh the window's content after it is displayed with the initial data.

The best *approximation* of this functionality is to close the old window and open a new one with the new data in every iteration - but note that this will be visually disruptive.

In the simplest case, move the `Out-GridView` into the loop and call it with `-Wait`, which requires you to close it *manually* in every iteration, however:

```
# NOTE: Doesn't move to the next iteration until you manually close the window.
while (1) { ps | select -first 5 | Out-GridView -Wait }
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51544510/45375) shows how to implement an auto-closing `Out-GridView` window, but it is a nontrivial effort - and with a sleep period as short as `1` second it will be too visually disruptive.

Ultimately, **what you're looking for is a GUI version of the Unix [`watch`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watch_(Unix)) utility** (or, more task-specifically, the [`top`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top_(software)) utility).

However, since you're not looking to *interact* with the `Out-GridView` window, **there's little benefit to using `Out-GridView` in this case**.

**Instead, you could just spawn a new *console* window that uses `Clear-Host` to display the output in the same screen position periodically:**

The following defines **helper function `Watch-Output`** to facilitate that:

```
# Simple helper function that opens a new console window and runs
# the given command periodically, clearing the screen beforehand every time.
function Watch-Output ([scriptblock] $ScriptBlock, [double] $timeout = 1) {
  $watchCmd = @"
   while (1) { 
     Clear-Host
     & { $($ScriptBlock -replace '"', '\"') } | Out-Host
     Start-Sleep $timeout 
   }
"@                                                                                                            #'
  Start-Process powershell.exe "-command $watchCmd"
}

# Invoke with the command of interest and a timeout.
Watch-Output -ScriptBlock { ps | Select -First 5 } -Timeout 1
```

Note that this will still *flicker* every time the window content is refreshed.
Avoiding that would require substantially more effort.

The [`PowerShellCookbook` module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PowerShellCookbook) offers the sophisticated `Watch-Command` cmdlet, which not only avoids the flickering but also offers additional features.
The **big caveat** is that - as of version `1.3.6` - the module has several cmdlets that conflict with built-in ones (`Format-Hex`, `Get-Clipboard`, `New-SelfSignedCertificate`, `Send-MailMessage`, `Set-Clipboard`), and the only way to import the module is to allow the module's commands to *override* the built-in ones (`Import-Module PowerShellCookbook -AllowClobber`).